# The distance issue between nodes in tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, spacing, positioning, nodes

I am  trying to place two nodes in the northeast and and northwest of another node. However, I am facing a visual issue.

Here is the example that I am working on.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows,positioning}
\begin{document}


\tikzstyle{block} = [rectangle, draw, fill=white!20,  node distance=3cm,
    text width=6em, text centered, rounded corners, minimum height=3em]
\tikzstyle{line} = [draw, very thick, color=black!50, -latex']


\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=2,node distance = 2cm, auto]
    \node [block] (A) {Initial step};
    \node [block, right =of A] (B) {The next step};

    \begin{scope}[node distance=4cm and 5cm]
        \node [block, right = of B, anchor = south east] (C) {The third step};
        \node [block, right = of B, , anchor = north east ] (D) {The fourth step};
    \end{scope}

    \path [line] (A) -- (B);
    \path [line] (B) -- (C);
    \path [line] (B) -- (D);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

The first issue is that as you can see I have different horizontal distances between nodes. The second problem is that I am not able to add vertical distance between nodes as shown in the image.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As suplement to @farahfeza  [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/577575/the-distance-issue-between-nodes-in-tikz/577583#577583):

- I would define `node distance` only once:

  - uniform distance in diagram,
  - shorter code
- Use of `tikzstyle` is deprecated, instead it you should use `\tikset` or define styles in `tikzpicture options (as is done in MWE below)
- Also library `arrows` is deprecated. Instead it is better to use more powerful  `arrows.meta`

```
\documentclass[margin=3.141592]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,
                positioning,
                shapes}
                
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
 node distance = 5mm and 22mm, 
  block/.style = {draw, rounded corners, fill=#1,
                  minimum height=3em, text width=6em, align=center},
block/.default = white,
every edge/.append style = {draw=black!50, thick, -Latex}
                    ]
\node [block] (A) {Initial step};
\node [block, right =of A] (B) {The next step};
\node [block, above right = of B] (C) {The third step};
\node [block, below right = of B] (D) {The fourth step};
%
\path   (A) edge (B)
        (B.+5) edge (C.west) 
        (B.-5) edge (D.west);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: request explain `(B.+5) edge (C.west) 
        (B.-5) edge (D.west);`

Comment: @jsbibra, `(B+5)` is the same as `(B.5)` define anchor on shape borders which lie on intersection of line rotated for 5 degrees from shape center and shape border. The same is valid for `B.-5` which is equal to `B.355`, where angle of rotation is -5 degree (= 355 degree).  Is your comment about this? BTE, `edge` can connect only two coordinates, style connection lines can be determined by `tikzset` or by option to `tikzpicture` as is done in answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can specify the relative x and y positions separately using the tikz library positioning, like this.

```
\documentclass[margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows,positioning}
\begin{document}

\tikzstyle{block} = [rectangle, draw, fill=white!20,  node distance=3cm,
    text width=6em, text centered, rounded corners, minimum height=3em]
\tikzstyle{line} = [draw, very thick, color=black!50, -latex']


\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=2,node distance = 2cm, auto]
    \node [block] (A) {Initial step};
    \node [block, right =of A] (B) {The next step};

    \begin{scope}[node distance=4cm and 5cm]
        \node [block, above right= 1cm and 4cm of B, anchor = south east] (C) {The third step};
        \node [block, below right= 1cm and 4cm of B,  anchor = north east] (D) {The fourth step};
    \end{scope}

    \path [line] (A) -- (B);
    \path [line] (B.10) -- (C.180);
    \path [line] (B.-10) -- (D.180);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Is it not sufficient to define `node distance` only ones (out of style definitions, out of scope)?

Comment: @Zarko, I produced a solution based on the OP's code. You may add a supplement to my answer.